# OpenHAB in Raspbian : Could not connect: Connection Refused

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, debugging, logging

When I am browsing to http://localhost:8082/openhab.app?sitemap=demo
I get the following error (even after clearing my complete history cache and cookies):

```
Could not connect: Connection Refused.
```

`ls -l` shows `-rwxrwxrwx root root` for `demo.sitemap` file in the `sitemaps` folder of `openhab`.

So when I do `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8082` nothing shows but I receive this error:

```
FAILED SelecyChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082:java.net.BindException: Address Already in use.
```

I have used `8082` anywhere in the whole openhab folder that was using `8080`. 
Any idea how could this be fixed?

Also `sudo lsof -i :8080` shows the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo lsof -i :8080
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java 756 openhab 128u IPv6 12383 0t0 TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

While:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo lsof -i :8082
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I am a little confused as I want to run the openHAB on port `8082` rather than port `8080`.

I have changed the `8080` to `8082` in the following files. Please let me know if that is wrong?

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/openhab $ grep -irn 8082 *
configurations/openhab_default.cfg:10:myopenhab:localPort=8082
configurations/sitemaps/demo.sitemap:63:    Image url="http://localhost:8082/images/splash-ipad-h.png" label="openHAB" {
configurations/openhab.cfg:10:myopenhab:localPort=8082
hs_err_pid850.log:210: 0x64cab800 JavaThread "qtp22705751-37 Acceptor1 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082" [_thread_in_native, id=891, stack(0x63080000,0x630d0000)]
hs_err_pid850.log:212: 0x64ca8c00 JavaThread "qtp22705751-35 Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082" [_thread_blocked, id=889, stack(0x63120000,0x63170000)]
hs_err_pid850.log:899:jvm_args: -Dosgi.clean=true -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Djetty.port=8082 -Djetty.port.ssl=8443 -Djetty.home=. -Dlogback.configurationFile=configurations/logback.xml -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=addons -Dfelix.fileinstall.filter=.*.jar -Djava.library.path=lib -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./etc/login.conf -Dorg.quartz.properties=./etc/quartz.properties -Dequinox.ds.block_timeout=240000 -Dequinox.scr.waitTimeOnBlock=60000 -Dfelix.fileinstall.active.level=4 -Djava.awt.headless=true 
logs/openhab.log:57:2016-03-21 00:00:02.501 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
logs/openhab.log:2666:2016-03-21 04:00:02.768 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
logs/openhab.log:5288:2016-03-21 08:00:02.530 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
logs/openhab.log:7893:2016-03-21 12:00:02.422 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
logs/openhab.log:9577:2016-03-21 14:37:10.712 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
logs/openhab.log:9957:2016-03-21 15:12:42.574 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
logs/openhab.log:11910:2016-03-21 18:12:32.480 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
logs/openhab.log:13106:2016-03-21 20:00:02.255 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
logs/openhab.log:14823:2016-03-21 22:38:22.039 [WARN ] [.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle] - FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
logs/openhab.log:17638:2016-03-21 23:31:24.496 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
logs/openhab.log:19789:2016-03-22 00:00:03.276 [INFO ] [.myopenhab.internal.MyOHClient] - Disconnected from my.openHAB service (UUID = 9519133a-991a-49e3-bd0c-829cc285444d, local base URL = http://localhost:8082)
Binary file server/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/94/data/store/org.openhab.myopenhab.pid.1 matches
Binary file server/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/94/data/store/org.openhab.myopenhab.pid.2 matches
server/eclipse.ini:6:-Dorg.osgi.service.http.port=8082
start_debug.sh:9:HTTP_PORT=8082
start.sh:9:HTTP_PORT=8082
```

And I have the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.18-v7+ #846 SMP Thu Feb 25 14:22:53 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /opt/openhab/
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/openhab $ ls
addons     configurations  etc                LICENSE.TXT  README.TXT  sounds     start_debug.bat  start.sh  webapps
addons_bk  contexts        hs_err_pid850.log  logs         server      start.bat  start_debug.sh   test      workspace
```

This is the permission of files:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/openhab $ ls -l /opt/openhab/
total 164
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 20480 Mar 22 19:39 addons
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi   pi    4096 Mar 22 19:31 addons_bk
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root  4096 Mar 22 20:24 configurations
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Feb  1 10:51 contexts
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root  4096 Mar 10 01:09 etc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 70135 Mar 10 01:09 hs_err_pid850.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11232 Feb  1 10:51 LICENSE.TXT
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Mar 22 00:00 logs
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   874 Feb  1 10:51 README.TXT
drwxrwxrwx 6 root root  4096 Mar 22 21:14 server
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Feb  1 10:51 sounds
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   996 Feb  1 10:51 start.bat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1146 Feb  1 10:51 start_debug.bat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1132 Mar 22 20:26 start_debug.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   969 Mar 22 20:24 start.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Mar 15 00:56 test
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root  4096 Mar 21 23:02 webapps
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root  4096 Mar  9 04:52 workspace
```

I am using `OpenHAB version 1.8.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was new to OpenHAB I had installed it both manually and also from the apt-get so the one from apt-get had been installed to `/usr/share/openhab`and was running in the background and was autostared everytime. I stopped that by '$ sudo /etc/init.d/openhab stop' command. Also I checked to see if anyone is using port 8080 or 8082 before running it (`sudo lsof -i :8080`). You only need to specify in `start.sh` file and not in `openhab_default.cfg` or `openhab.cfg` files that you want to use another port than `8080` by `HTTP_PORT=8082` in `start.sh` file.

```
Remove openhab from autostart:
sudo update-rc.d openhab remove
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `HTTP_PORT` variable in `start.sh` or `start_debug.sh` is sufficient. Using `8082` instead of `8080` works as well, and I'm able to open the UI.

[image]

To be certain: you are using `localhost` in the url, but openhab is running on a Raspberry Pi. Does that mean you are using a browser on the Pi itself?

Comment: yeah I am using the browser in pi

Comment: - which version of openhab and raspbian are you using ?
- which addons are active and which ones do you need ?
- what happens if you try another port, say 8083 ?
- can you post your configs ?

Comment: `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.18-v7+ #846 SMP Thu Feb 25 14:22:53 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux` I am not sure which version of OpenHAB I am using I have this file structure in the openhab folder:
`pi@raspberrypi:/opt/openhab $ ls
addons     configurations  etc                LICENSE.TXT  README.TXT  sounds     start_debug.bat  start.sh  webapps
addons_bk  contexts        hs_err_pid850.log  logs         server      start.bat  start_debug.sh   test      workspace`

Comment: can you please report what is the permission of files in your openhab directory? ls -l /opt/openhab/

Comment: @Frederick What do you use to communicate with devices? *(RaspBee, Elelabs ZigBee, CC2531, ConBee 2)*